# Why no green padlock in my Wordpress site while everything using HTTPS protocol?

Tags: wordpress, https

For me, this is a serious issue, and I searched and tried every possible way to solve it. 
The Homepage for my wordpress blog has a Green padlock in address bar, but not in post's.

This is the Blog's Homepage 
[Screenshot Homepage of my blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHQst.jpg)
And here is the Source code while searching for HTTP link or anything. 
[Screenshot Source code of my blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcY96.jpg)
It has only one http part which is from google analytics and don't have a problem with green padlock. Everything seems fine.

But when I'm on post's page

This page too has only one http element ( that google analytics ) and it is not secure ! No green padlock, (This page contains....which is not secure) Can anyone help me with this ? What should I do ?

Comment: You've cut off half the information in the second screenshot and not provided any information from the other page so impossible to answer! You might be loading the whole page over http for all we know! There's a new Security tab in Developer tools in latest version of Chrome which shows any security issues which might prevent a green padlock showing when on https. Suggest you check that out.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had more screenshot, but my reputation is a bit low, so can't upload more than two images.

Comment: Okay, I'm downloading latest chrome and will let know if found the problem.

Comment: From a very quick search I can see lots of http references on that page. Including the stylesheet.

Comment: I.m not forcing users to HTTPS, and my theme coded like "/style/style.css"

Comment: Please use https:// before the address.

Comment: Line 45 for example has this even when loaded over https: <link rel='stylesheet' id='stylesheet-css' href='http://www.yourserver.com/blog/wp-content/themes/schema/style.css?ver=4.4.2' type='text/css' media='all'/>. This will result in an insecure content warning and loss of green padlock.